# SQLAlchemy force to bulk insert with bindparam()

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

If I use `bindparam()` in the insert statement SQLAlchemy force to bulk insert.. e.g.

```
stmt = insert(some_table).values(
            timestamp=bindparam('timestamp', type_=Integer),
            some_id=bindparam('some_id', type_=Integer),
            a=0,
            b=0,
            c=0,
            d=0
        )
result = session.execute(stmt, {'some_id': 123, 'timestamp': int(time.time())})
```

the value of `result` is `sqlalchemy.engine.result.IteratorResult`, that means I can not get the last inserted id by `result.lastrowid`

but this code is different

```
stmt = insert(some_table).values(
            timestamp=int(time.time()),
            some_id=123,
            a=0,
            b=0,
            c=0,
            d=0
        )
result = session.execute(stmt)
```

Now the value of `result` is `sqlalchemy.engine.cursor.CursorResult`, and I can get the last inserted id by `result.lastrowid`

Any advice on why this behavior and how do I get the last inserted id from the first one

Thanks for helping